# Train a single pytorch model on multiple GPUs with some layers fixed?

Tags: python, machine-learning, parallel-processing, gpu, pytorch

I met some problems when using pytorch [`DistributedDataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html). The situation is:

1. My model is **A**, and it has been trained on a **single** GPU as usual. Suppose that there are three layers in **A**:

   ```py
   class A(nn.module):
       def __init__(self):
           super(A,self).__init__()
           self.layer0 = layer0
           self.layer1 = layer1
           self.layer2 = layer2

       def forward(self,x):
           x=self.layer0(x)
           x=self.layer1(x)
           x=self.layer2(x)
           return x
   ```
2. Now I have some new data. I want to **fine-tune** A with it on **multiple** GPUs. I need to wrap **A** as a multi-GPU model **B**.
3. But there are **two** training stages. In the 1st stage, I want to **fix** `layer0` and `layer1` of **B**. In the 2nd stage, only to fix `layer0`. Then `requires_grad` of parameters in `layer1` should be changed during training.  However, `DistributedDataParallel` [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#distributeddataparallel) says:

   > You should **never** try to change your model’s parameters after wrapping up your model with DistributedDataParallel.

In fact, I tried to use `B.module` to refer **A** wrapped in **B**. But the test results were abnormal compared to the single-GPU model. Maybe this way is disallowed.

What should I do? Is there any proper way to wrap my model? And what should be take care for when saving and loading the model?

Just run it on a **single machine** with multiple GPUs so you can ignore the distributed situation using multiple machines. Many thanks.

**Update 2019.12.03**

As suggested by @jodag, I tried `DataParallel`, but it didn't work. This time I didn't change anything in **B** (except training it) after wrapping it. For simplification, My code is like this (and I refered [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/16885#issuecomment-551779897)):

```py
class B(nn.DataParallel):
     def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return super().__getattr__(name)
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(self.module, name)
a = A()
b = B(a,device_ids=[0,1])
b = b.cuda()
trained_param = b.layer2.parameters()
# trained_param = [{'params':b.layer2.parameters()},{'params':b.layer1.parameters()}]
optimizer = optim.Adam(trained_param)
b.train()
...
for x, label in data_loader:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    x = x.to(0) # This line can be commented.
    y = b(x)
    l = loss(y, label)
    l.backword()
    optimizer.step()
```

Comment: `DistributedDataParallel` isn't strictly necessary here. You could try wrapping your model in `DataParallel` instead which will distribute the model to all the local GPUs on the machine.

Comment: @jodag Thanks. I tried it and it behaved the same unfortunately. See the update.

Comment: I closed this question because there may be other things cause it. I have to debug it with my code. The information provided here may be not enough to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you only try to optimize part of the parameters, why not try controlling this via the *optimizer*, rather than the model?
You can leave your model as-is (wrapped in a `DistributedDataParallel`) and pass only part of its parameters to the relevant optimizer.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. First I set `requires_grad=True` in layer1 and layer2 in **A**. Then it's wrapped as **B**. In 1st stage, I passed `B.module.layer2.parameters()` to the optimizer. In 2nd stage, I passed `B.module.layer1.parameters()` too. I have checked that the weight in each GPU can be changed by the optimizer and they were synchronized. But as mentioned above the results were much worse than the same configuration except trained on single-GPU. So I ask for help that what's the correct implementation.

Comment: @Kani can you do the same just without meddling with `required_grad`?

Comment: I tried to switch to `DataParallel` without changing `required_grad` after wrapping and it behaved the same unfortunately. See the update.

Comment: @Kani what is the behavior that you expect and what is occuring to make you think it's misbehaving?

Comment: @jodag When I used a single GPU, the loss on training set declined as usual and the precision on test set increased gradually up to 83% in my two-class task. When I used two GPUs, the outputs on test set all gave the same class label (label 0). I checked that the output score of label0 was always larger than label1.  But I didn't change the batch size or learning rate or anything. It just moved the data from one GPU to two GPUs. I think the results should be similar, right?